# How Can I prove (a+b) mod m = (a mod m) + (b mod m)) mod m?

Tags: modular-arithmetic

### modular arithmetic

How Can I prove (a+b) mod m = (a mod m) + (b mod m)) mod m ?

Comment: Before it can be proven, you have to have a definition for $\rm mod$.  What is your definition of it?

Comment: This question is a bit confusing. You seem to have too many (mod m)s. Are you trying to prove equality in Z of least positive representatives or equality in Z/mZ?

Answer (score 2):

Let $a\mod m= a_1$ and $b\mod m = b_1$.

Then

$$\begin{cases}m\mid a-a_1\\m\mid b-b_1\end{cases}\implies m\mid a+b-(a_1+b_1)$$

$$\iff a+b\equiv a_1+b_1\pmod{m}\iff (a+b)\mod m=(a_1+b_1)\mod m\\\iff (a+b)\mod m =((a\mod m)+(b\mod m))\mod m\ \ \ \square$$

Comment: I am not clear about the notation m|a . please explain.

Comment: You need to be careful here. If you say $a mod m= a_1$ then a is an integer and $a_1$ is a set of integers. This causes some problems.

Comment: $m\mid a$ is the notation for "$m$ divides $a$", or "$a$ is divisible by $m$". Formally, $m\mid a\iff \exists k\in\mathbb Z(a=mk)$.

Comment: @SE318 No. See [this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic#Remainders). $a\mod m$ is defined to be $r$ such that $a=lm+r$ for some integer $l$, where $r\in\mathbb Z, 0\le r<m$.

Comment: @user314, I see what you're saying. I've never seen it defined in this way in any of my math classes though as this lead to ambiguity as to if you're just finding the remainder, or passing into the quotient space. It's probably just a difference in definitions though, depending on which textbook you use, they can define these things with slight(but important!) differences.

Comment: @SE318 You might have in mind the modular equivalence relation and equivalence of integers there. $a\equiv b\pmod {m}$ just means that $m\mid a-b$, and $b$ can be any integer of the form $b=wm+a, w\in\mathbb Z$.

Comment: Yeah, I just looked at my undergraduate AA book (AA an introduction 2nd edition by Hungerford). In there, they define modular arithmetic solely in terms of arithmetic in Z/mZ. I can definitely see how using it to just define the remainder after the division algorithm could be used as well(especially in a more CS/application based math course rather than a purely abstract math course)

Comment: @user26486. Thank you very much. Can you show how to do it for $ ab \mod m = (a \mod m)(b \mod m) \mod m$

Comment: How we can we conclude that $$(a+b)\mod m=(a\mod m+b)\mod m?$$I try use your idea but I get stuck.

Answer (score 1):

Using $\,\ c\equiv d\pmod m\color{#c00}\iff \bar c = \bar d,\ $
 where $\,\ \bar n := (n\bmod m)\ $

${\rm mod}\ m\!:\,\ a\color{#c00}\equiv \bar a$
$\qquad\qquad\, b\color{#c00}\equiv \bar b$
$\ \, \Rightarrow\,\ a+b\equiv \bar a + \bar b\,\ $ by the $ $ [Congruence Sum Rule](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/879262/242)

$\color{#c00}\Rightarrow\, (a+b)\ {\rm mod}\ m\, \equiv\, (\bar a + \bar b)\ {\rm mod}\ m,\,\ $ which is the titled claim.

**Remark** $ $ Generally, as above, to prove an identity about mod as an operator it is usually easiest to first convert it into the more flexible congruence form, prove it using congruences, then convert back to operator form.

Answer (score 0):

If $\pmod m$ just means that you subtract or add multiples of $m$ until you end up in the range $0,1,2,...,m-1$ then the RHS is easily compared to the LHS by collecting multiples of $m$.